# MySQL and PHP issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, edit

I am trying to learn some MySQL database.

The tutorial (unfortunately is in polish language so I am not gonna link it here) explains me how to make a database on hosting site. It tells me to create base with 3 lines. And then I should be able to edit these lines or delete through website. I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my code, could you help?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<?
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost","lazyorr","aq12wsxx");
mysql_select_db("nwwnd");



$wynik = mysql_query("select id,link from menu order by id");

while ($w = mysql_fetch_row($wynik)) 
{
echo $w[1]." - ";
echo "<A HREF=\"pobieranie.php?p=e&id=$w[0]\">edytuj</A> ";
echo "<A HREF=\"pobieranie.php?p=u&id=$w[0]\">usuń</A><BR>";
}

if ($_GET["p"] == "u") {
mysql_query("DELETE from menu where id = ".$_GET["id"]);
}

if ($_GET["p"] == "e") {
$wynik = mysql_query("select * from menu where id =".$_GET["id"]);
$w = mysql_fetch_row($wynik);
echo "<FORM METHOD=\"post\" ACTION=\"pobieranie.php\">";
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"link\" VALUE=\"$w[1]\"><BR>";
echo "<TEXTAREA NAME=\"tresc\">$w[2]</TEXTAREA><BR>";
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"hidden\" NAME=\"id\" VALUE=\"$w[0]\"><BR>";
echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" VALUE=\"edytuj\">";
echo "</FORM>";
}

if ($_POST["link"] != "" && $_POST["tresc"] != "") {
echo "<BR>Zaktualizowano.";
mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET link =".$_POST["link"]."',tresc    ='".$_POST["tresc"]."' where id =".$_POST["id"]);
}

mysql_close($sql);
?>
```

If you would like to see the website go [here](http://nwwnd.cba.pl/mysql/pobieranie.php)

My table name: menu
It contains three lines ID - (int(3)) Link - (varchar(100)) Tresc - (text)

(int(3)) contains AUTO_INCREMENT function

Table

```
ID  Link     Tresc
1   Link 1   Link 1
2   Link 2   Link 2
3   Link 3   Link 3
```

Comment: I'd recommend finding a new tutorial that uses PDO or mysqli. mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7, deprecated in previous versions, and are horribly insecure.

Comment: as @aynber says, this is a horribly outdated tutorial. learn PDO

Comment: Well... this tutorial is recommended by my professor and he requires knowledge that it contains... But thank you for your advice

Comment: @JuliuszUrbańczyk As much as you probably have to pass your course, anyone recommending `mysql_query` is severely misguided. It's been such a blight on PHP that it was removed in PHP 7. If possible, use PDO. If not, **escape** everything using `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid [injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Nothing your professor says will ever change the fact that this won't work in a current version of PHP. For up-to-date recommendations see [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very first thing which you are missing is right php tag.

Next, check with you php version.

Newer version of php has deprecated mysql functions. Use mysqli or PDO instead. If you are using older version try installing ph5-mysql first.